# How to compile C++ classes to .wasm files for wasmer?

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to compile a C++ library (pure code) to a **.wasm** file for **Wasmer** so I can run them universally in the server side regardless of what OS it's on. However I find rare documentation which can help me deal with C++ class.

For details, all helpful functions I wanted are in a C++ class named *Timer*, like `Timer.reset()`. But it seems that Wasmer can only use `exported functions` on it's documentation. So it is possible to use exported c++ classes like `instance.exports.Timer.reset()` in Wasmer?

The main confusion is also about how to wrap this `Timer` class in .wasm file. I checked emscripten doc which shows [this](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#classes). But the documentation compile them to `.js` files instead of `.wasm`.

Questions above combined, I find it hard to get clear procedures to use c++ classes in Wasmer for other programming languages.

I hope I've made a clear problem explanation for anyone willing to give some hints. Bests.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following pull request: [Enable accessing fields that are classes without copying](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/pull/17602/files).

Using it, you can expose C++ classes as properties using the following example (from the PR):

```
class Foo {
public:
  int i;
};

class MyClass {
public:
  int x;
  Foo foo;
  int getY() const { return y; }
  void setY(int y_) { y = y_; }
private:
  int y;
};

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(test) {
  class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
    .constructor()
    .property("x", &MyClass::x) // Expose a field directly.
    .property("y", &MyClass::getY, &MyClass::setY) // Expose through a getter and setter.
    .property("readOnlyY", &MyClass::getY) // Expose a read only property.
    .property("foo", &MyClass::foo); // Expose a class field.
  class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .constructor()
    .property("i", &Foo::i);
}
```

Then in Javascript, you can use the following code to use them:

```
var myClass = new Module.MyClass();
myClass.x = 10;
myClass.x; // 10
myClass.y = 20;
myClass.y; // 20
myClass.readOnlyY; // 20
// Assign directly to the inner class.
myClass.foo.i = 30;
myClass.foo.i; // 30
// Or use Foo object to assign to foo.
var foo = new Module.Foo();
foo.i = 40;
// Note: this will copy values from the foo but the objects will remain separate.
myClass.foo = foo;
myClass.foo.i; // 40
myClass.delete();
foo.delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can do "the old way" wrapping it in c calls:

```cpp
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

class Foo {
public:
  int i;
};

class MyClass {
public:
  int x;
  Foo foo;
};

typedef void *MyClassHandle, *FooHandle;

MyClassHandle createMyClass() {
    return static_cast<MyClassHandle>(new MyClass());
}

void destroyMyClass(MyClassHandle handle) {
    delete static_cast<MyClass *>(handle);
}

FooHandle getFoo(MyClassHandle handle) {
    MyClass *This = static_cast<MyClass *>(handle);
    return static_cast<FooHandle>(&This->foo);
}

int getFooInt(FooHandle foo) {
    return static_cast<Foo *>(foo)->i;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(test) {
    function("createMyClass", &createMyClass, emscripten::allow_raw_pointers());
    function("destroyMyClass", &destroyMyClass, emscripten::allow_raw_pointers());
    function("getFoo", &getFoo, emscripten::allow_raw_pointers());
    function("getFooInt", &getFooInt, emscripten::allow_raw_pointers());
}
```